# How to resign textview when UITableView Scrolls

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell`, and a `UITextView` was put inside this prototype cell. When I click on this textView, keyboard can bounce automatically. However, if I want to hide the keyboard, I will have to click Return key. It isn't quite convenient.

Here's the question. How can I resign the textView's `firstResponder` for hiding the keyboard when I scroll the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Add `UITableViewDelegate` and add the below method:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        view.endEditing(true)
}
```